# Creating a while loop which takes a random return from a method

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm trying to write a loop that will run a method, and return the results at least once. the getResults() method returns a string containing either "Throw again" "win" or "lose", and if it returns "throw again" it continues to loop, breaking otherwise.

This code currently sends me into an infinite loop whenever I get the "Throw again". I notice that the loop only runs getResults() once to take the results. However, I'm unsure how to have that loop run the method again then check for the string after each 'Throw again'.

```
public String playCraps() {
        String results;
        do {
            getResults();
            results = getResults();
            System.out.println(results + "\n*************");
        } while (results.contains("Throw again"));
        return "\n*********";
    }
```

EDIT getResults() method.

```
public String getResults() {
        String die1 = "Dice 1 is " + dice1.getFaceValue();
        String die2 = "Dice 2 is " + dice2.getFaceValue();
        String total = "Total is: " + addUpScore();
        String result = "Result is " + decideOutcome(addUpScore());
        String message = die1 +"\n" +die2+"\n"+total+"\n"+result;
        return message;
    }
```

EDIT 2 - 1st returns the output that I want each time I press run (output from getResults() is random). 2nd shows that getResults() doesn't change no matter how many times I call through a loop or instruction.

```
public String playCraps() {
        return getResults();
    }
```

```
public String playCraps() {
        System.out.println(getResults());
        getResults();
        System.out.println(getResults());
        getResults();
        String message;
        message = getResults();
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: May you add getResults() here as we are unable to get what getResults() return.

Comment: Why are you calling getResults() twice?

Comment: Your calling getResults() twice and the first time it doesn't look like it doing anything.

Comment: Your code works correctly _**depending on the results from getResults()**_ - it appears `getResults()` is returning `Throw again` repeatedly. We'll need to see it.

Comment: Now it looks like decideOutcome(addUpScore()) might be the problem can we see that code?

Comment: @JaredCS included now. score input is just the sum of two randomly rolled dice.

Comment: you should be able to debug it. When you hit that "infinite loop". It seems your output is always Throw again. check the number you input in decideOutcome. You seem to never hit these numbers 7,11,2,3,12 again once you are in that "infinite loop". maybe you make a strange addup or the dice is not rolling only 6 faces.

or as some users suggestested print the value you input in decideOutcome. You'd really want to know what the console outpust are.

Comment: Can we see the addUpScore() code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String result = "Result is " + decideOutcome(addUpScore());
```

this is wrong. you should put a variable in what is he adding up when you have no input? I would expect that you would input

```
 String result = "Result is " + decideOutcome(addUpScore(dice1.getFaceValue(), dice2.getFaceValue()));
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(playCraps());
    }
    
    public static String playCraps() {
        String results;
        do {
            results = getResults();
            System.out.println(results + "\n*************");
        } while (results.contains("Throw again"));
        return "\n*********";
    }
    
    public static String getResults(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int max = 6;
        int min = 1;
        int dice1Value = rand.nextInt((max+1) - min) + min;
        int dice2Value = rand.nextInt((max+1) - min) + min;
        int score = dice1Value + dice2Value;

        String die1 = "Dice 1 is: " + dice1Value;        
        String die2 = "Dice 2 is: " + dice2Value;
        String total = "Total is: " + score;
        return "Result is:"+ "\n" + die1 +"\n" +die2+"\n"+total+"\n" + decideOutcome(score);
    }
    
    public static String decideOutcome(int score){
        String message = new String();
        if(score == 7 || score == 11) {
            message = "You win";
        }
        else if(score == 2 || score == 3 || score == 12) {
            message = "You lose";
        }
        else {
            message = "Throw again";
        }
        return message;
    }
    
}
```

1st output:

```
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 5
Dice 2 is: 5
Total is: 10
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 4
Dice 2 is: 1
Total is: 5
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 3
Dice 2 is: 6
Total is: 9
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 5
Dice 2 is: 6
Total is: 11
You win
*************

*********
```

2nd output:

```
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 5
Dice 2 is: 5
Total is: 10
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 4
Dice 2 is: 5
Total is: 9
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 4
Dice 2 is: 5
Total is: 9
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 3
Dice 2 is: 6
Total is: 9
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 4
Dice 2 is: 4
Total is: 8
Throw again
*************
Result is:
Dice 1 is: 1
Dice 2 is: 2
Total is: 3
You lose
*************

*********
```

Comment: So there's a lot of methods relying on each other for this to work which I get isn't perfect (the dice values for example), just the way I've been told to do it. I have tested each step and all methods work up to calling getResults() in playCraps(). each time I call playCraps() without the loop it gives me a different output so the input from getResults()does change. what I'm struggling with is getting the loop to recall getResults() so it takes a new input instead of the same one over and over again.

Comment: @MatWDS I edited a working example which i fiddled with https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/
you might take a look into it

as I said i think you have an error in `addUpScore()` when adding up or calculating the sum of both dice faces. or before. As you can see, your loop works just fine, also your `decideOutcome()`function works just fine. you put

Comment: Thanks, this worked so I just worked backwards to see which part was ruining it. My problem lied with my dice value not being generated each time they were used. Think the way I've been told to do this sparks a lot of issues that normally I wouldn't come across.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your loop logic is just fine! getResult() should be getting run each time through, but I believe it is always returning "Throw again" there must be an issue with getResult();

**Edit**

Id recommend trying this to debug:

```
public String getResults() {
    String die1 = "Dice 1 is " + dice1.getFaceValue();
    System.out.println(die1);
    String die2 = "Dice 2 is " + dice2.getFaceValue();
    System.out.println(die2);
    String total = "Total is: " + addUpScore();
    System.out.println(total);
    String result = "Result is " + decideOutcome(addUpScore());
    System.out.println(result);
    String message = die1 +"\n" +die2+"\n"+total+"\n"+result;
    System.out.println(message);
    return message;
}
```

**Edit**

Here some code I got to work.

```
public String playCraps() 
{
  String results;
  System.out.println("");
  int counter = 0;
  do 
  {
    counter++;
    results = getResults(counter);
    System.out.println(results + "\n*************");
  } while (results.contains("Throw again"));
  return "\n*********";
}

public String getResults(int counter)
{
    System.out.println("in getResults");

  if(counter > 3)
  {
    return "win";
  }

  return "Throw again";
}
```

Results:

```
in getResults
Throw again
*************
in getResults
Throw again
*************
in getResults
Throw again
*************
in getResults
win
*************

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edit**

It now appears that addUpScore() is the problem.

Comment: I've included the getResults() above, I have tested it and it does return "win" and "lose" statements too.

Comment: have you looked in the return value of getResults()? I believe decideOutcome() might be wrong here. I believe theres something wrong and the string contains always Throw again

Comment: Have tested return values of getResults() and decideOutcome(), both have the correct returns and do return 'win' or 'lose' when they should. So surely the problem lies within the loop?

Comment: Maybe add those println() I recommended and show us the output you are getting.

Comment: you just make a counter in the loop that after 3 throws is always greater than 3. did you just do it to proof that the loop is working correctly?

Comment: @Roadman1991 Yes, the code shows the loop is working.  If "Throw again" is returned it keeps looping, if "Win" is returned it stops.  Which is the desired behavior of the loop I believe.

Comment: The issue with playCraps() is that when it calls getResults() it only fetches a new output when I press run, and not when the loop goes through it. So getResults() returns a different output as it should each time I press run, but the loop does not call it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fault might be in `getReults()`, you might want to use:

```java
int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
if(rand == 1) {
    return "throw again";
} else if(rand == 2){
    return "win";
} else { 
    return "lose"; 
}
```

Comment: getResults() method works fine and returns correct strings. "win" "lose" "throw again" all appear when they should do, however once "throw again" is returned it enters an infinite loop.